# What split-screen options are available in Battlefront?

Tags: ps4, xbox-one, star-wars-battlefront-2015

How many players can play split-screen, and what game modes are (or aren't) available?

- How many players can play local co-op?
- How many players can play local multiplayer?
- How many players can play online multiplayer from a single console?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. 2 Players can play local co-op.
2. 2 Players can play local multiplayer.
3. 1 Player can play online multiplayer from a single console.

Splitscreen play is limited to non-online mission modes in the new Battlefront.

Comment: Local only isn't a huge problem, but limited to only 2 players? That's disappointing...

Comment: @Jim I agree. I was hoping for more. It seems they were very focused on framerate, and when they did local multiplayer with just 2 people the framerate would drop to 30fps. That's as low as they wanted it to go, I guess.