# Star Wars Battlefront Splitscreen

Tags: star-wars-battlefront-2015

I am considering purchasing Star Wars Battlefront (the new one from DICE), and saw that it had a split-screen mode. Is this only available when doing the "Missions" or can you play in split-screen in the multiplayer modes too?

Comment: Where do you intend to play it? PS, XBOX or PC? Since there is - unfortunately - no splitscreen on PC at all. And on the consoles framerate is reduced on 30 FPS and still unperformant.

Comment: Duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/243815/32055

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Star Wars BattleFront for consoles, "Multiplayer" is only available for one player. You cannot do online multiplayer with split-screen.

Split-screen is only available in the game for non-online mission modes, like Survival. Split-screen play is also limited to only two players.

It's worth noting that splitscreen multiplayer is *not* available on the PC version.